# How to add code to calculate the price and concatenate it to the orderMessage

Tags: javascript, css, html

This is the whole program and all the "//" are the things my professor wants me to do to the program, help on the whole thing would be amazing but just helping me get a start will be great too. I dont really understand what I need to do and what to add in to make it work. Ive tried a few things and it hasnt worked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"> 
    <head>
    <title>JavaScript Project T-Shirt Order</title>
    <script>
     /*
     *  Function OrderTShirt
     *
     *  Inputs:
     *     selectedColor - initialized from the select tag with id="colorChoice"
     *     selectedStyle - initialized from the select tag with id="style"
     *     selectedSize  - initialized from the select tag with id="size"
     *
     *  Output:
     *      alert of the order message
     *
     */
     function OrderTShirt(){

       //initialize the input
       var selectedColor = document.getElementById("colorChoice").value;
       var selectedStyle = document.getElementById("style").value;
       var selectedSize =  document.getElementById("size").value;


       //create the orderMessage to alert - you may want to move/change this code
       var orderMessage = "Your order is:  Color = " + selectedColor 
                      + "; Style = " + selectedStyle 
                      + "; Size = " + selectedSize+"\n";


       //Add code to calculate the price and concatenate it to the orderMessage
       var price = document.getElementById()
       //For example, "The order is:  Color = gray; Style=T-Shirt; Size = XL \nThe price is $7" 

       //If the style and size are not available, then concatenate the message that 
       // the selection is not available instead of a price.

       // a t-shirt in any size is $7 except 2XL which is $10.
       // a v-neck in adult sizes is $12.50 except the 2XL is not available
       // a tech shirt in adult sizes is $13

       alert(orderMessage);
   }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>
    <table>
      <tr/>
      <tr><th>Colors</th><th>Styles</th><th>Sizes</th></tr>
      <tr><td>
    <select id="colorChoice">
      <option value="gray">Gray</option>
      <option value="gold">Gold</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="pink">Pink</option>
      <option value="white">White</option>
      <option value="navy">Navy</option>
      <option value="maroon">Maroon</option>
      <option value="black">Black</option>
      <option value="royalblue">Royal Blue</option>
      <option value="limegreen">Lime Green</option>
    <select>
       </td><td>
    <select id="style">
      <option value="T-Shirt">T-Shirt</option>
      <option value="Tech Shirt">Moisture Wicking Tech Shirt</option>
      <option value="Ladies V-Neck">Ladies V-Neck - Adult sizes only</option>
    </select>
      </td><td>
    <select id="size">
      <option value="XS">Adult Extra Small</option>
      <option value="S">Adult Small</option>
      <option value="M">Adult Medium</option>
      <option value="L">Adult Large</option>
      <option value="XL">Adult Extra Large</option>
      <option value="2XL">Adult 2X</option>
    </select>
      </td></tr>
      <tr/><tr><td>
          <input type="button" 
                 value="Order T-Shirt" 
                 onclick="OrderTShirt();">
       </td><td/><td/>
    </table>
    <p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Java != Javascript

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is what I think you are looking for. I made another function called getPrice that will calculate the price for you. It checks the style of the shirt, and then following the examples you gave it checks what the size is and then gives a price, or "Unavailable" if there are none in stock.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"> 
    <head>
    <title>JavaScript Project T-Shirt Order</title>
    <script>
     /*
     *  Function OrderTShirt
     *
     *  Inputs:
     *     selectedColor - initialized from the select tag with id="colorChoice"
     *     selectedStyle - initialized from the select tag with id="style"
     *     selectedSize  - initialized from the select tag with id="size"
     *
     *  Output:
     *      alert of the order message
     *
     */
     function OrderTShirt(){

       //initialize the input
       var selectedColor = document.getElementById("colorChoice").value;
       var selectedStyle = document.getElementById("style").value;
       var selectedSize =  document.getElementById("size").value;


       //create the orderMessage to alert - you may want to move/change this code
       var orderMessage = "Your order is:  Color = " + selectedColor 
                      + "; Style = " + selectedStyle 
                      + "; Size = " + selectedSize+"\n";


       //Add code to calculate the price and concatenate it to the orderMessage
       var price = getPrice(selectedColor, selectedStyle, selectedSize);

       if(price === "Unavailable") {
           orderMessage += "This shirt is not available";
       } else {
           orderMessage += "Price = " + price;
       }
       //For example, "The order is:  Color = gray; Style=T-Shirt; Size = XL \nThe price is $7" 

       //If the style and size are not available, then concatenate the message that 
       // the selection is not available instead of a price.

       // a t-shirt in any size is $7 except 2XL which is $10.
       // a v-neck in adult sizes is $12.50 except the 2XL is not available
       // a tech shirt in adult sizes is $13

       alert(orderMessage);
   }

    function getPrice(color, style, size) {
        var price;

        if(style === "T-Shirt") {
            if(size === "2XL") {
                price = 10;
            }else {
                price = 7;
            }
        }
        else if(style === "Ladies V-Neck") {
            if(size === "2XL") {
                // Unavailable
                price = "Unavailable"
            }else {
                price = 12.50;
            }
        }
        else if(style === "Tech Shirt") {
            price = 13;
        }

        return price;
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Colors</th>
                <th>Styles</th>
                <th>Sizes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="colorChoice">
                        <option value="gray">Gray</option>
                        <option value="gold">Gold</option>
                        <option value="red">Red</option>
                        <option value="pink">Pink</option>
                        <option value="white">White</option>
                        <option value="navy">Navy</option>
                        <option value="maroon">Maroon</option>
                        <option value="black">Black</option>
                        <option value="royalblue">Royal Blue</option>
                        <option value="limegreen">Lime Green</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="style">
                        <option value="T-Shirt">T-Shirt</option>
                        <option value="Tech Shirt">Moisture Wicking Tech Shirt</option>
                        <option value="Ladies V-Neck">Ladies V-Neck - Adult sizes only</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="size">
                        <option value="XS">Adult Extra Small</option>
                        <option value="S">Adult Small</option>
                        <option value="M">Adult Medium</option>
                        <option value="L">Adult Large</option>
                        <option value="XL">Adult Extra Large</option>
                        <option value="2XL">Adult 2X</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="OrderTShirt();">Order T-Shirt</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```